# How to use available libraries from within mbed-os?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, arm, mbed

I have pulled down a fresh copy of mbed-os by using the *mbed-cli* tool.

```
$ mbed new mbed-os-test
[mbed] Creating new program "mbed-os-test" (git)
[mbed] Adding library "mbed-os" from "https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os" at latest revision in the current branch
[mbed] Updating reference "mbed-os" -> "https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/#dda7f7d77abd4330b05e686ce3bbe58230eb7876"
```

Ultimately I am working to enable uVisor on my NXP FRDM-K64F device, but for now I am only using the [QuickStart](https://github.com/ARMmbed/uvisor/blob/master/docs/api/QUICKSTART.md) tutorial to get a simple example working without enabling the uVisor.

So, as suggested in the link above, I make a `source` directory in the newly created clone of mbed-os:

```
$ mkdir mbed-os-test/mbed-os/source
```

I copy in the basic `main.cpp` and compile. It works. However, when I try and create a problem using some of the library routines -- specifically [EthernetInterface](https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Ethernet-Interface).

Replacing my simple `main.cpp` from the uVisor example with the more complicated one (using EthernetInterface) from the above link:

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "EthernetInterface.h"

int main() {
    EthernetInterface eth;
    eth.init(); //Use DHCP
    eth.connect();
    printf("IP Address is %s\n", eth.getIPAddress());

    TCPSocketConnection sock;
    sock.connect("mbed.org", 80);

    char http_cmd[] = "GET /media/uploads/mbed_official/hello.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n";
    sock.send_all(http_cmd, sizeof(http_cmd)-1);

    char buffer[300];
    int ret;
    while (true) {
        ret = sock.receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
        if (ret <= 0)
            break;
        buffer[ret] = '\0';
        printf("Received %d chars from server:\n%s\n", ret, buffer);
    }

    sock.close();

    eth.disconnect();

    while(1) {}
}
```

Compiling with:

`mbed compile -m K64F -t GCC_ARM`

I am met with compilation errors stating that the EthernetInterface class does not have members that I am trying to invoke.

```
../../mbed-os/source/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../../mbed-os/source/main.cpp:34:9: error: 'class EthernetInterface' has no member named 'init'
     eth.init(); //Use DHCP
         ^
../../mbed-os/source/main.cpp:36:38: error: 'class EthernetInterface' has no member named 'getIPAddress'
     printf("IP Address is %s\n", eth.getIPAddress());
                                      ^
../../mbed-os/source/main.cpp:38:5: error: 'TCPSocketConnection' was not declared in this scope
     TCPSocketConnection sock;
     ^
../../mbed-os/source/main.cpp:39:5: error: 'sock' was not declared in this scope
     sock.connect("mbed.org", 80);
     ^
```

When, of course, the EthernetInterface class *does* have such members. I think the problem is related to the mbed utilities not compiling against the correct source code because it seems to find the header. If I add a `--source=` option to the mbed compilation I am met with other errors regarding things that EthernetInterface.cpp includes.

`mbed compile -m K64F -t GCC_ARM --source=../libraries/net/eth/EthernetInterface/`

```
[ERROR] In file included from ../libraries/net/eth/EthernetInterface/EthernetInterface.cpp:19:0:
../libraries/net/eth/EthernetInterface/EthernetInterface.h:27:18: fatal error: rtos.h: No such file or directory
```

The files are certainly contained with mbed-os, I am just not sure how to actually *use* them.

```
$ find . -name EthernetInterface.cpp
./libraries/net/eth/EthernetInterface/EthernetInterface.cpp
./features/net/FEATURE_IPV4/lwip-interface/EthernetInterface.cpp
```

---

**tl;dr** -- How can we link against the library code given at `libraries/`? I can directly include the header files by directly including the file, but the corresponding source appears to be that located in the `features/` directory rather than the one in `libraries/`.

Comment: The question says mbed OS, but the documentation you've linked is for mbed Classic, which is not the same thing. [I don't see any `init()` member here](https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-api/en/mbed-os-5.1.0/api/features_2net_2FEATURE__IPV4_2lwip-interface_2EthernetInterface_8h_source.html) (nor in the superclasses).

Comment: @Notlikethat, What is the difference? In my final `find` command at the end of the question there are two results: the first in `libraries` is the source corresponding to the documentation [here](https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Ethernet-Interface) while the latter, in `features`, is the same source you have linked to in your comment. If I include "EthernetInterface.h" in my source it seems to include the latter rather than the former (which has more features, like `init` and others).

Comment: _"This documentation covers the networking libraries available for mbed 2. For mbed 5, the networking libraries have been revised to better support additional network stacks and thread safety [here](https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-api-reference/en/5.1/APIs/communication/network_sockets/)."_ - as I understand things, mbed Classic (version 2) is basically just a set of HAL libraries, whereas mbed OS (version 5) is a full-blown connectivity-focused RTOS, and there are significant source-level incompatibilities between the two. Can't say I've ever actually used either myself, though.

Comment: @Notlikethat, Thanks for the links! Given that, what I am trying to do, then, is link against the EthernetInterface.cpp sources for mbed 5 rather than mbed 2. It seems the latter is the default case for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering what you're doing that I'm missing, because this works for me:

```
$ mbed new ethernet-test
$ cd ethernet-test
$ mbed target K64F
$ mbed toolchain GCC_ARM
```

Open `ethernet-test/main.cpp` and put in:

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "EthernetInterface.h"

int main(int, char**) {
  EthernetInterface eth;
  eth.connect();
}
```

Then:

```
$ mbed compile
...
Total Flash memory (text + data + misc): 108092 bytes
Image: ./.build/K64F/GCC_ARM/ethernet-test.bin
```

Comment: Indeed it works, but, as I found out, the EthernetInterface implementation with more features (like static assignment rather than using DHCP), found [here](https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Ethernet-Interface), has not yet made it into mbed5 yet ([source](https://developer.mbed.org/questions/73258/How-does-mbed-cli-create-includes-and-li/)). Although both implementations are included in the mbed repo, only [this](https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-api-reference/en/5.1/APIs/communication/network_sockets/) one is actually compiled and linked against.

Comment: Although interestingly, the API that I mention above ([shown here](https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-api-reference/en/5.1/APIs/communication/ethernet/)) does not actually work. If you look at the source files in the `features` directory (see OP, `libraries` has the full implementation, `features` seems to have a subset) it only has the code for the `Public Member Functions` and not the `Static Public Member Functions` from that link. Try using one of the status member functions -- .e.g EthernetInterface.init(), or similar; it does not work.